Why elastic bodies give more sound during collision?
I have a doubt. We call a material elastic when there is very little loss of kinetic energy. However, when we strike two metal rods, they produce a high-amplitude sound compared to when we collide or strike two less elastic rods, such as plastic rods.

At what occasion " there is very little loss of kinetic energy" and why less energy loss if you don't hear a sound? So ask a precise question!

You are implying that metal rods are non elastic. Yes, that's correct, what is the question?

@trula so this is the question if metal rods are elastic so why there is lot of sound , because we studied that elastic material has very less loss of kinetic energy

@damnOk, what you are saying that metal rods are non elastic . this is not true metal rods are highly elastic as they deform very less

@Akshanshbansal I'm sorry I'm still wondering, but I think the energy produced in a lot of sound is even less than the energy contained by the rod. You know, if you could calculate the energy in normal talking sound wave (around 60 decibels), it would probably be very less in decimals in joules. Whereas the rods may have integral values of energy in joules.

Sound energy is one avenue of energy loss after a collision, but it's only because of air that this energy is lost.
If elastic rods are struck together, they will start vibrating because they don't permanently deform. Then if the rods are in a medium like air, the vibrations are transferred to the medium, bleeding off the energy as sound waves. If this collision happened in space, then the rods would continue vibrating without losing energy, like you were expecting. (Real materials will still eventually lose energy as there is internal friction.)
Plastic, the material, has an elastic regime just like many other materials, so the same analysis applies. But even collisions that plastically deform the objects interact with the air and also produce sound waves.
The amplitude and pitch of the sound probably depends on other properties like hardness and stiffness of the material. Metals are very hard and stiff and are able to "ring". Plastic, the material, doesn't ring, perhaps because it is too soft.
